# RSA Vulnerability when the Encrypted M is not coprime with N

Tags: rsa

I have tested out with a few test cases, it seemed like the ciphertext $M^e$ of RSA is always coprime with N when e=3. Is there a reason why? What would happen if the ciphertext $M^e$ is not coprime with M when e=3?

Comment: When $(N,e)$ is a valid RSA public key with $N$ the product of two distinct secret primes $p$ and $q$, there's probability about $1/p+1/q$ that a random message $M$ is such that $M^e$ is not coprime with $N$. Since both $p$ and $q$ must be large (hundreds of decimal digits) for RSA to be secure, that probability is entirely negligible in actual use of RSA. The question is considering something that in actual use won't occur for random or pseudorandom $M$, or for $M\in[1,N)$ chosen by one not knowing (nor able to find) the factorization of $N$.

Comment: RSA is a trapdoor permutation. Does this imply you anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $N = pq$ is the product of two primes, the only numbers which aren't coprime to $N$ are those that contain either $p$ or $q$ as a factor. It is certainly possible to have $M^3$ divisible by either $p$ or $q$ so your observation is not true in general. An example:

$$
M = 42\\
N = 7*13 = 91\\
M^3 \equiv 14 \pmod{91}
$$
Clearly 14 and 91 are not coprime - they both share $7$ as a factor. Computing the GCD of $c = M^3$ and $N$ thus leaks $7$ as a factor of $N$, breaking RSA.

Comment: Ok, I did not think of this. In that case, it is a severe security vulnerability, since by taking the GCD of the ciphertext(C) and N leaks p or q?

Comment: Would using OAEP on a C that is not coprime with N dissolve the issue?

Comment: @Chen: I don't get what you means by "using OAEP on C"; but using OAEP to produce the input $M$ for raw RSA encryption $M\mapsto C=M^e\bmod N$ for otherwise secure $N$ is practically certain to "dissolve the issue", if there was one. Now we can safely encipher multiples of $p$ or $q$. Again, even when not using OAEP, there is no practical issue, because choosing $M$ or $C$ in $[1,n)$ with $\gcd(C,N)\ne1$ is impossible for one not knowing (nor able to find) the factorization of $N$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to use OAEP on M. Do you mean that to chose a M that gives $gcd(C,N)≠1$ on purpose is impossible without knowing p and q?

Comment: and why would that be impossible? Would it be still possible with a probability of success of 1/p + 1/q?

Comment: @Chen it would be no different to an attacker just guessing random factors of $N$ :)

Comment: @Chen: for practical sized $p, q$, that is, $2^{-1024}$ or smaller, $1/p + 1/q$ is effectively "impossible"